# Can I combine an if condition with a fetch on a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm developing a Stored Procedure that should take some in parameters. One of those parameters tells me how many records I should take, but if it's value is 0 or less, then it should fetch all of the rows. I developed the following solution which I don't like:

```
IF (@take > 0) BEGIN
    SELECT
          *
    FROM Properties
        -- Some conditions and joins are here using other parameters
        -- A big Order by with cases is placed here
    OFFSET @skip ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @take ROWS ONLY;
END
ELSE BEGIN
            SELECT
          *
    FROM Properties
        -- Some conditions and joins are here using other parameters
        -- A big Order by with cases is placed here
    OFFSET @skip ROWS;
END;
```

The problem with the above condition is that I have to make sure that the SQL statemants are equal except for the last line inside the if condition. One of the approaches I also tried was to contruct a query string and execute it using EXEC, but one of the variables will come directly from the user and thus I am vulnerable to SQL injection.

I will also have to improve the above code to allow the SP to receive a parameter telling if it should 'group by' by some field, which will make me add another branch into each of those conditions (So the above solution is not very scalable). Is there a better approach?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever . . . I misread that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression rather than using your `@take` variable directly:

```
SELECT
      *
FROM Properties
    -- Some conditions and joins are here using other parameters
    -- A big Order by with cases is placed here
OFFSET @skip ROWS
FETCH NEXT CASE WHEN @take > 0 THEN @take ELSE 1000001 END ROWS ONLY;
```

Of course, that does require you to pick a "big enough" constant for the `ELSE` that is larger than any reasonable result set that you expect your query to return. I usually pick a round number and add one, with the intention that I'll display up to "round number" results and if I get that extra result, I can at least include an indicator that the query returned even more results than that.

This is based on the assumption that the user is controlling the filtering and you want to be/are able to say "you know what, there are too many results. Use the paging functionality if you really want to work through all of them but I'm not going to attempt to show them all to you now".

---

> I will also have to improve the above code to allow the SP to receive a parameter telling if it should 'group by' by some field

That's a trickier proposition. A query with a `GROUP BY` clause necessarily entails a `SELECT` clause that contains columns covered by the `GROUP BY` clause or *aggregate expressions*. (and if there are no aggregates, what's the point of the grouping?). That looks fundamentally different to a non-grouping query and so you can't really switch between them with a simple switch/flag.

At that point, the queries are unlikely to have much similarity (except maybe the `FROM` clause that you may wish to move into a view or table-valued function for reuse purposes), or you will need to switch to dynamic SQL.

Comment: Not the solution I really wanted but the best solution available.